# Why is the behavior of setTimeout(0) and setImmediate() undefined when used in the main module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, race-condition, event-loop

Take the following code taken from the [nodejs event loop documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) :

```
// timeout_vs_immediate.js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout');
}, 0);

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log('immediate');
});
```

According to the documentation :

> For example, if we run the following script which is not within an I/O
>   cycle (i.e. the main module), the order in which the two timers are
>   executed is non-deterministic, as it is bound by the performance of
>   the process.

Why is the above statement true ? Is it because the nodejs runtime actually employs more than one thread to pick out the callbacks that have to be executed.

What my intuition says: there are two threads that execute callbacks for `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` so when both of them are available this leads to a race condition, and thus the output will be non-deterministic.

Is it correct ? Or is there any other reason for which this is non-deterministic ?

Comment: I know this is a bit long but there is no better explanation than [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-understanding-node-js-event-loop/)

Comment: Good question! I've read the node.js event loop document very carefully but failed to find the explanation. It seems the document only tell us it-would-be-non-deterministic, but never mention why.

Comment: @shaochuancs do you think it is non-deterministic by design ?

Comment: @ng.newbie No, I don't think it's by design. I guess this non-deterministic behaviour can be explained by some internal Node.js mechanism. Unfortunately, no document/article is found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/how-is-timing-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-bound-by-the-performance

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, two things happen:

1. setTimer(0..) gets converted into setTimer(1..)
2. before the (next) event loop tick begins, node/libuv has to perform a clock_gettime() to get the current time from the system. The time taken for this system call is non deterministic as it depends on the system load at that time. Now, if clock_gettime() took more than 1ms, the setTimer callback will run (#), else event loop continues to next phase (##).

   - In case (#), setTimeout(0,..) callback is run before setImmediate()
   - In case (##), it is otherwise.

Reference:
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/392#issuecomment-305969168

Comment: True. This should be the answer.