# Precedence of setImmediate() and setTimeout() callbacks in CommonJS vs ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs, event-loop

Calling setTimeout with setImmediate has unpredicted behaviour if using CommonJS modules. But if you switch to ESM ("type": "module" in package.json), it will always execute setImmediate before setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout');
}, 0);

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log('immediate');
});
```

Why does this happen? Is it related to the fact that in ESM modules are loaded asynchronously?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518968/process-nexttick-vs-queuemicrotask-in-commonjs-and-esm-what-is-the-execution-order answer your question even if it's about different functions?

Comment: it is related, but a bit different. there are talking about microtasks but my question about macrotasks.

Comment: Ah actually it might not be related to the module type at all, it's just that order between `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` is non-deterministic (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72834122, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23269153, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38076585, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57285104, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45934350, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62501823 and many more)

Comment: It is non-deterministic in CommonJS. 
But in ESM order is alway the same. And that is my question)

Comment: On a "what should happen" note, there is no "zero millisecond" interval for setTimeout, [it will always be at least 1ms](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#settimeoutcallback-delay-args). Having said that: please describe what "unpredictable behaviour" is in your post, and then it's probably a good idea to not log regular text, but log `Date.now()` or `performance.now()` values so that it's clear what really happens, because `console.log` is itself has timing issues. It doesn't run "when your code says it should run" so you want to make sure that the _data_ it logs tells you when things ran.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `console.log` is synchronous and subsequent calls will log their arguments in the right order, there is no problem with that.

Comment: How do you know that it „is determenistic“? How many times did you run it? How did you run it?

Comment: @bergi console log timing is explicitly not defined in the spec, and if you've ever gone "why does the array/object I'm console logging have the content from _after_ the console log?" you'll have run into console log not _actually_ being synchronous.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's about the debugger inspecting a logged object (and still does not mean that log lines are in the wrong order). This has nothing to do with the question here.

Comment: Maybe, but console logging actual time stamps and showing the result of those runs in the post itself is still pretty much required for this to meet the posting guidelines. If their timeouts don't behave the way they're supposed to, I'm not betting on their console logs behaving either.

Comment: No time to dig this up entirely but that's probably caused by both the points Bergi mentioned.  First, the non-deterministic aspect is only appearing when ran from the "main module", i.e. when ran out of the I/O cycle. Then when loaded as ESM the script is probably ran in the I/O cycle (that's the point I'd need to double check, I see a call to `open` when doing a --trace-event that's not here for CJS).

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that as determined in prior Q/As, like [1](/q/72834122), [2](/q/23269153), [3](/q/38076585), [4](/q/57285104), [5](/q/45934350), [6](/q/62501823) and many more (thanks Bergi for the list), with the best "in-depth" explanation being maybe done in [this issue comment](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/392#issuecomment-305969168); **the indeterminate order of `setImmediate()` and `setTimeout()` only happens when calls are made from the "main module".**

When ran as ESM, the main script is actually always delayed by one task because of an async call to [`OpenFileHandle`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0090c107820ce3e9f41f6b3271b5022f709a638e/src/node_file.cc#L1939), which is truly asynchronous, and not just spawning a new microtask.

Here is the actual JS trace that leads to there:

```
Trace:
    at open (node:internal/fs/promises:633:11)
    at readFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1243:20)
    at getSource (node:internal/modules/esm/load:46:20)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:137:40)
    at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:404:13)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:286:56)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:65:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:298:17)
    at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:255:34)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:235:17)
```

[Source of `ModuleLoader.getModuleJob`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0090c107820ce3e9f41f6b3271b5022f709a638e/lib/internal/modules/esm/loader.js#L233) if you want to walk that up.

So we're actually out of the aforementioned "main module", but instead in the `I/O` phase and now the order is deterministic, immediate, then timeout.

Comment: This answer can wrong foot everyone who will be reading it. You are observing the RESULT of  `uv__io_poll` coming before `uv__run_check` & `uv__run_timers` and I gave an exact scenario where callbacks would be registered before/after `uv__io_poll` in my answer which deals with the IO operations you are observing in ESM. If a new version of Node would be released and placement of  `uv__io_poll` would be altered, you would observe a different behavior. A core dev just confirmed my answer. Without this, you cannot explain the non deterministic behavior in CommonJS

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I left that leg-work to the 7 links at the top of my answer. Yes, we know why it's non-deterministic in CJS. That's not the question here. The question is *why is it deterministic in ESM*. The answer is, *because they do call `OpenFileHandle` with the async signature, which will move the event-loop to the IO phase, where the order of execution is deterministic.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin If you do invert `uv__io_poll`, you'd still have a deterministic behavior, just the inverse one. However if in `getSource (node:internal/modules/esm/load:46:20)` you do replace `readFileAsync` with `readFileSync` you have a non-deterministic behavior. (I only built and tested the `getSource` change).

Comment: "If you do invert uv__io_poll, you'd still have a deterministic behavior, just the inverse one." Yes and that's the point. `readFileSync` will have downstream bindings to register timers/immediates that can be non-deterministic and `uv__io_poll` will end up separating 1st eventloop and 2nd one will start prepopulated with `uv__run_timers`. This is evident in the C part, not the JS. I do not know where the resistence to not see it comes from

Comment: Because the actual question is **what makes it deterministic when ran as ESM**. The actual difference between CJS and ESM is the JS call to `readFile`. Sure it then triggers the C issue, but the difference is here, in the JS part.

Comment: `but the difference is here, in the JS part`. No it absolutely is not. The difference is there is a routine to `uv__io_poll` that is triggered by  your `ModuleLoader.getModuleJob`, all the way to your `readFile` that skips the first cycle, and starts `uv__run_check` prepopulated as I stated. You are observing the result NOT the cause. I'm done. I do  not think it is possible to portray what is going on anymore differently.

Comment: "that is triggered by ..." -> That's what we usually call a cause, yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a CommonJS environment, such as Node.js, the execution order between `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` can be unpredictable when called in quick succession with a very short delay (like 0 milliseconds). This is due to the way Node.js handles CommonJS modules and their synchronous loading.

With ESM (ECMAScript Modules) and the `"type": "module"` option set in `package.json`, modules are loaded asynchronously and follow a more standardized event handling model. In this case, because modules are loaded asynchronously, `setImmediate` is more likely to be executed before `setTimeout`, even with a delay of 0 milliseconds.

One possible solution to ensure the desired execution order is to use a code structure that doesn't rely on the order of module loading. For instance, you can use `setImmediate` or `setTimeout` with a slightly larger delay than 0 milliseconds to ensure the desired order:

```
setImmediate(() => {
  console.log('immediate');
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout');
}, 1); // Use a slightly larger delay than 0
```

This way, you might ensure that `setImmediate` is executed before `setTimeout`, regardless of the module loading behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Both are similar but might show different behaviour if it's called during some process or alone.

From [the official documentation of Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick):

> - **`setImmediate`** is designed to execute a script once the current poll phase completes.
> - **`setTimeout`** schedules a callback to be run after a minimum threshold in ms has elapsed.
>
> The order in which the timers are executed will vary depending on the context in which they are called. If both are called from within the main module, then timing will be bound by the performance of the process (which can be impacted by other applications running on the machine).

**Case 1**

If run the above code in main module and without any other process or IO call, we cannot determine the order of both the timers and it is determined by the performance of the process.

**Case 2**

If you call this during an IO call, the immediate callback is executed first, **always**.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(__filename, () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 0);
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('immediate');
  });
});
```

**As ES modules have asynchronous execution, it comes under case 2 and guarantees that `setImmediate` executes the callback first.**

References:

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#require

https://nodejs.org/en/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick

Comment: Please mark your quotes appriopriatelly and link to the original sources. Also, what makes you say that ES modules come "under case 2"? Where is it said that they are ran outside of the main module?

Comment: As the last bold line says - As ES modules have asynchronous execution, it comes under 2. You can refer to node.js official documentation.

Comment: Please calm down @kaiido, It's a question about Node.js/JavaScript. Anything someone answers here is going to be based on respective language documentation and concepts - no one can create their own concepts. And it is not called plagiarism if its based on official documentation - which whole purpose is to to be read, shared, discussed in order to understand the respective language. Spend your energy in doing something productive instead of shouting on someone.

Comment: I am calm, I'm sorry if you perceived any animosity in my comments, I probably didn't formulate correctly. That being said, it's now the third time I ask you to mark properly the quotes in your answer as quotes. You still didn't comply while it's this site's rule to do so. And yes, people do make stuff up, all the time, most don't do it on purpose, but rather because they're mislead somehow. Still, we want high standard answers here and this means we want reliable sources without having to read an entire environment's documentation searching for a vague idea.

Comment: Please *clearly mark* which content is taken from elsewhere. See [the referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Right now, your post fails to comply.

Answer (score 0):

I started my search here: [lib/timers.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a53fd95d363f1897549a074a53d29590d58f2dc7/lib/timers.js). Here note 3 things:

1- [binding](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a53fd95d363f1897549a074a53d29590d58f2dc7/lib/timers.js#L32C1-L32C43):

```js
const binding = internalBinding('timers');
```

This is the C binding from [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv), we will come to that.

2- [timerListQueue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a53fd95d363f1897549a074a53d29590d58f2dc7/lib/timers.js#L50):

```js
function unenroll(item) {
  ...
  timerListQueue.removeAt(list.priorityQueuePosition);
  ...
```

Above is used by `clearTimeout` to control the timers to be registered/removed.

3- [immediateQueue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a53fd95d363f1897549a074a53d29590d58f2dc7/lib/timers.js#L51C14-L51C14):

Likewise, this is used by `clearImmediate`

So this first part is to establish that `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` use 2 distinct queues.These queue objects are controlled by `Timeout` and `Immediate` respectively here:

```js
const {
  ...
  Timeout,
  Immediate,
  timerListQueue,
  immediateQueue,
  ...
} = require('internal/timers');
```

Going to `internal/timers`:

```js
class Immediate {
  constructor(callback, args) {
    ...
    immediateQueue.append(this);
  }
```

And for the [timeout](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a53fd95d363f1897549a074a53d29590d58f2dc7/lib/internal/timers.js#L132-L146):

```js
let timerListId = NumberMIN_SAFE_INTEGER;

const kRefed = Symbol('refed');

let nextExpiry = Infinity;
// timeoutInfo is an Int32Array that contains the reference count of Timeout
// objects at index 0. This is a TypedArray so that GetActiveResourcesInfo() in
// `src/node_process_methods.cc` is able to access this value without crossing
// the JS-C++ boundary, which is slow at the time of writing.
timeoutInfo[0] = 0;

// This is a priority queue with a custom sorting function that first compares
// the expiry times of two lists and if they're the same then compares their
// individual IDs to determine which list was created first.
const timerListQueue = new PriorityQueue(compareTimersLists, setPosition);

// Object map containing linked lists of timers, keyed and sorted by their
// duration in milliseconds.
//
// - key = time in milliseconds
// - value = linked list
const timerListMap = { __proto__: null };
```

`class Timeout` does not directy use it, instead it is assigned a `this.id = timerListId++;`. Throughout this file, you will see references to C++ bindings [everywhere](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a53fd95d363f1897549a074a53d29590d58f2dc7/lib/internal/timers.js#L360):

```js
// We need to use the binding as the receiver for fast API calls.
function insert(item, msecs, start = binding.getLibuvNow()) {
  // Truncate so that accuracy of sub-millisecond timers is not assumed.
```

So, I traced the main event loop of Node.js to [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a53fd95d363f1897549a074a53d29590d58f2dc7/deps/uv/src/unix/core.c):

```c
int uv_run(uv_loop_t* loop, uv_run_mode mode) {
  ... 
  uv__io_poll(loop, timeout);
  /* Process immediate callbacks (e.g. write_cb) a small fixed number of
  * times to avoid loop starvation.*/
  for (r = 0; r < 8 && !uv__queue_empty(&loop->pending_queue); r++)
    uv__run_pending(loop);
  ...
  uv__run_check(loop);
  ...
  uv__run_timers(loop);
  
  return r
}
```

so the Immediate's are executed in the `check` (`uv__run_check`) phase and the timeouts are executed in the `timers` (`uv__run_timers`) phase. How did I figure this out? I check the blog here: https://nodejs.org/en/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick and recognized the `uvlib` bindings.

So apparently the `uv__run_check`is always before `uv__run_timers`.

Then how did you observe the discrepancy between CommonJS and ESModules?

Keeping in mind that `setTimeout/setImmediate` register the calls via `bindings`, the `uvlib` execution order is ALWAYS consistent. What is not consistent is when and at what part of the event loop `setTimeout` or `setImmediate` register the callbacks through the bindings *(keep in mind that a script/module execution can span multiple event loops and subsequent setTimeout/setImmediate callbacks, although seemingly sync, can be registered at different points corresponding to different event loops)*:

- if a 0 delay `setTimeout` is called right before `uv__io_poll`, it might be executed in the current `uv__run_timers`
- if `setImmediate`'s calling time corresponds right after event loop enters `uv__io_poll`, it will be executed in the **NEXT** `uv__run_check`.

And this is how `setTimeout` can execute before `setImmediate` in CommonJS during synchronous execution. Putting it in other words, in the js script they might appear synchronous, but registration through bindings in the event loop cannot be controlled.

In the ES modules, the module has to wait for dependency resolution and thus has to span multiple event loops (at least 1) until execution starts, which gets `uv__run_check` prepopulated and therefore is always executed before.

Comment: "the module has to wait for dependency resolution and thus has to span multiple event loops (at least 1) until execution starts" That's actually the part that needs deciphering. The rest was already found out in the [previous related Q/As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77736974/precedence-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-callbacks-in-commonjs-vs-esm/77768308?noredirect=1#comment137047088_77736974).

Comment: Your comment is a bit misleading. None of those links mention in the check phase and the timer phase in the C code. And it is that part that is important. In ESM registering the callbacks through the bindings take longer compared to CommonJS because of async nature and check phase is guaranteed to contain items before the timer if any was encountered during parsing.  Is there a better way to explain this in layman's terms?

Comment: My point is that it's already been confirmed before that setImmediate and setTimeout can have non-deterministic order when ran from the "main module". We know that, it's been confirmed by node's devs. Yes, your answer does bring some good info about that, but it's not what's needed for *this* question. What we need here is the proof that when loaded as ESM, we're not in the "main module" anymore. Stating "it has to wait", or "take longer" without any resource to back up these claims isn't useful. They could very well also use sync loaders for the main ESM script like they do for CJS.

Comment: The reason I pasted this C code is precisely to illustrate that whether you are in main module or not not being relevant. CommonJS is sync, time window between parsing and registering callbacks via bindings is very small which can cause unexpected behavior in the first cycle of event loop. However ESM has to support top level await, which forces callbacks to be registered after the initial cycle and thus forces the de facto expectation that setImmediate executes before setTimeout. Maybe you have missed the C code where uv__run_check(loop); executes BEFORE uv__run_timers(loop); ?

Comment: But the fact that the main module is async doesn't mean that a new task will be queued. There is nothing async going on in OP's code before both calls to `setTimeout` and `setImmediate`. `(async () => { await Promise.resolve(); })()` does not queue a task but a microtask. The event loop would not change its phase based on that. You can even try to run OP's code wrapped in such an async function, and in CJS you will have the same non-deterministic behavior. Something when ran in ESM queues a task somewhere. That's what needs to be found.

Comment: Kaiido, the problem is you are trying to understand this from a higher level in JS medium  in terms of micro/macro tasks but really it is in 1 level below. Registering the callbacks via uvlib bindings involves not just wrapping stuff in async. please contact someone from core devs, I know a few I can refer to. This discussion can drag on for an eternity like this. I will contact Yagiz Nizipli, maybe he can help

Comment: No, the problem is that you are hand-waving the core of the issue. Why would registering callbacks to uvlib be different when ran as ESM? And if it is, show us where it is done differently.

Comment: Do not accuse me of things I have not done, return the favor by being civil. I contacted a core dev.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256528/discussion-between-kaiido-and-ibrahim-tanyalcin).

Comment: Morning, a core dev just confirmed what I said. https://x.com/ibrhmTanyalcin/status/1744543406326456598?s=20

Comment: But I never said that what you said was wrong, I only said it doesn't answer the question here. You are basically answering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/ and once again, your answer there would make a very good answer. But here the question is why when ran as ESM it becomes deterministic. Your answer doesn't provide the answer to that, apart from the vague and non-sourced "it has to span multiple event-loops".

Comment: Because of placement `uv__io_poll` which was the first example I gave!!! This corresponds to `getModuleJob` you are observing in your answer. Your answer is not the cause but the RESULT of `uv__io_poll`'s location in the for loop. I do not anymore know how this can be rephared so everyonebody understand what is going on.

Comment: But why are we in `uv__io_poll` when ran as ESM? This is the question here. And this is because when ran as ESM there is an async call to `readFile`, while in CJS it's a sync one. The placement doesn't really matter in determining whether the order is deterministic or not, it just matters about what will the deterministic order be.

Comment: it needs to read the file and dependents and that's the `uv__io_poll` OMG!

Comment: In CJS too it needs to read the file and dependencies, but it does so using `readFileSync` and thus doesn't always end up in the I/O poll phase when running the main-module.

Comment: You just confirmed the example I gave in my own answer. I'm done. I can't waste anymore.

Comment: Ok, let's take an image, that may not be perfect, but... A child takes a pen and draws on the wall. Then his parents ask "Why is there some drawings on the wall?" Your answer says "*because the molecules of the ink will get attached to the ones of the paint on the wall.*" (or whatever I'm not a chemist)  That's not wrong, but that would also be true even if the child didn't take that pen. The actual cause of the new drawing on the wall is that the child did take the pen to draw on the wall. Here what we are looking for is "what triggered" the different behavior.