# Why does setTimeout occur after Promise.resolve()

Tags: node.js, event-loop

In the event loop there are:

1. Phases of the event loop, each containing their own callback queue
2. Microtask queue, which includes resolved promise callbacks

As I understand it, the microtask queue runs after every phase of the event loop.

The first phase of the event loop is the "timers" phase. See here: https://blog.insiderattack.net/event-loop-and-the-big-picture-nodejs-event-loop-part-1-1cb67a182810

[image]

So given this code:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('TIMEOUT')); 
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('PROMISE');
```

I would expect the logs to read

```
TIMEOUT
PROMISE
```

But instead you get

```
PROMISE
TIMEOUT
```

I understand that the "PROMISE" log is from a callback in the microtask queue. But the timer phase is the first phase. If in each phase we first run the callback queue and THEN the microtask queue, why am I seeing the timer log after the log in the microtask queue?

Comment: The promise callbacks just run first

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your comment/help. I read this. Timers seems to be the first phase in the docs. Poling is 4th. So I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is ran from a task, and that after this initial task, there will already be a microtask checkpoint, just like after every task.

It's not very clear in the diagram, but even if you had 33 timer callbacks firing in the same phase, they would all empty the `nextTick` queue and the microtask queue, so there would have been like 33 such checkpoints.

Comment: What do you mean by a "task." My understanding is the stack clears, then the first phase is timers.

Comment: Whatever each phase executes. In the timer phase case it would basically be JS callbacks, but in the IO phase for instance it might be more internal stuff that aren't directly mapping to your JS code.

Comment: I really need to understand this question. You've responded to three of my posts and I still do not understand what you are saying. I appreciate the help, but your answer is not clear. The first phase is timers. There is no phase before timers, right? I need to understand why there's something before the first phase.

Comment: No, the first phase is not the timer phase, the first phase (in CJS) is the *main module*, in ESM it's actually the *IO* phase.

Comment: I have not seen any documentation on this. Can you please provide further reading. The Node docs says the timer phase is first. I really need some reading on this if it exists.

Comment: This NodeJS doucmentation says the poll phase checks for timers than have stopped. If it has stopped, node circles back to the timer phase to execute the timer callback. In that journey, it hits the microtask queue. https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick

That doesn't seem to match what you said. Is this what you meant?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#understanding-processnexttick as for what phase we're in initially I already gave you the link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77736974/precedence-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-callbacks-in-commonjs-vs-esm/77784120#77784120

Comment: This is the actual answer. The underlying C code runs timers as i/o operations with a timeout. So the polling phase populates the timer phase callback queue. The first time through, the timer queue has nothing in it. The the polling queue populates it. But the microtask queue runs before it can circle back to the timer phase a second time. 

It's covered here for people who want to know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883525/i-know-that-callback-function-runs-asynchronously-but-why/29885509#29885509

Comment: No, you misunderstood it, the nextTick and microtask queues are emptied after every task. It doesn't matter how the timers are scheduled, as I said, even doing `setTimeout(() => { queueMicrotask(() => console.log("microtask"); }); setTimeout(() => { console.log("second timeout") })` you'd get the microtask log first and the second timer second, even though it's fired in the same event loop iteration, because that's just how microtasks (and nextTick) works: they're fired after every task performed by the event loop.

Comment: The flow is 1) the stack is empties, 2) the event loop starts, 3) the timer phase. There isn't anything before that. The microtask queues are emptied after each phase. This is the first phase. The queue is initially empty because the underlying C is run as an i/o event. The polling phase therefore populates the timer callback queue. And you can't get from the polling phase to the timer phase without emptying the microtask queue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257086/discussion-between-kaiido-and-j-seabolt).

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` always runs after the execution of `current script`. So even if your Promise and setTimeout has a resolve time of 1s, the promise will be resolved first and only after that, the timeout will be triggered.

[Js info](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#zero-delay-settimeout)